# wordpress change home name to blog

Tags: php, wordpress, web

Can you please help me ,to change "Home" button name to "Blog" in word-press.

And later can i create a new page with "Home" name. Does it conflict with the default "Home" which
word-press already provides?

Many Thanks

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=getting+started+with+wordpress)

Comment: Sir..how can i change "home" button name to "blog" pls help

Comment: Depends on the template you are using, the site you have setup, the menu items, is it a wordpress.com site or a wordpress installation on another site, etc, etc... Read a tutorial on setting up wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your wp-include folder and open post-template.php file .Under this file search following code

```
    if ( ! empty($args['show_home']) ) {
    if ( true === $args['show_home'] || '1' === $args['show_home'] || 1 === $args['show_home'] )
        $text = __('Home');
```

Now change $text from Home to your desired one.

Comment: Excellent Swapnesh... Thanks a tonn

Comment: And how can i order the buttons..means..i have blog,home,partners,contactus..and i want to change to Home,partners,contactus,blog.. please help sir

Comment: Sir..I have done ordering pages.but the renamed Blog(from home button), is in the first page, i cant able to order this page.And am ordering the pages by this way, open/edit page in the right bottom side, there is "order" field is there, iam mentioning 1 and 2 like that. But i cant able to order the "Blog"(Home") page, Please help

Comment: Create menus from backend, its a dropping effect for creating desired menu under Menu tab. Add pages. categories etc then under "theme location" select your menu to primary menu. I hope this make sense to you and sorry for late reply :)